# I can't re-login to a JSF page unless I close my browser or restart my Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

index.xhtml is my login page

I made a Realm using SHA-256 as encryption algorithm in Glassfish

and Session.java is login bean that contains :

```
package beans;


import java.security.MessageDigest;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 *
 * @author bk-laptop
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "mngsession")
@SessionScoped
public class Session {

    private String userid;
    private String password;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of Session
     */
    public Session() {
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String login() throws ServletException {

        if (this.userid.isEmpty()) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Please enter a user !!!");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("form-login:usernameInput", message);

            return null;
        }

        if (this.password.isEmpty()){
             FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Please enter a password !!!");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("form-login:usernameInput", message);
            return null;
        }

        //context.addMessage(null,new FacesMessage("Ok"));
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {


            request.login(this.userid, this.password);
        } catch (ServletException e) {

            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Login Failed !!!");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("form-login:usernameInput", message);

            return null;
        }

        return "/products/List";

    }

    public void logout() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try {
            request.logout();

        } catch (ServletException e) {

        }

    }

    private String sha256(String base) {
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] hash = digest.digest(base.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & hash[i]);
                if (hex.length() == 1) {
                    hexString.append('0');
                }
                hexString.append(hex);
            }
            return hexString.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);

        }
    }


}
```

When I login for the first time Im able to go to /products/List and the login is successful but when I logout and re-login the login is failed ... Plz help ...

This is the code of the index :

```
<form   id="form-login" method="POST" action="j_security_check">
            <div style="text-align: center;" >
                <div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: auto; max-width: 480px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 2px solid #0361A8; border-radius: 5px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #0361A8; margin: 50px auto auto;">
                    <div style="background: #0361A8; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding: 15px;">
                        <span style="font-family: verdana,arial; color: #D4D4D4; font-size: 1.00em; font-weight:bold;">Enter your login and password</span></div></div></div>
            <div style="background: ; padding: 15px">


           <p><strong>Please type your user name: </strong>
                <input type="text" name="j_username" size="25" /></p>
            <p><strong>Please type your password: </strong>
                <input type="password" size="15" name="j_password" /></p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
            </p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and I've put the logout in the template.xhtml :

```
<p:menuitem value="Sign out"  actionListener="#{mngsession.logout()}" outcome="/index" />
```

Servlet : ManageLogin.java

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


            try {
           String username;
           String password;
           username = request.getParameter("j_username").toString();
           password = request.getParameter("j_password").toString();
           request.login(username, password);
           System.out.println(username+password);
           response.sendRedirect("template.xhtml");
           System.out.println("hi");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);
           response.sendRedirect("error.xhtml");
       }
```

And web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ManageLogin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>beans.ManageLogin</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ManageLogin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>admin</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/users/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/groups/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>bob</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Do you get an exception when you try to re-login?  (You may have to printout the catched exception to see it)

Comment: INFO:   javax.servlet.ServletException: This is request has already been authenticated
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:2242)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:2229)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1113)
 at beans.Session.login(Session.java:75)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Comment: Looks like you are not really logged out. Are you sure that the logout method is working and not throwing an exception?

Comment: No exception in the logout method

Comment: Your code is working for me...please add your XHTML code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Further digging showed that a similar problem was achieved while using **BASIC authentication**. In which case the user is only logged out on closing the browser.

If you are using BASIC authentication - it is tied to the browser. It will require closing the browser to completely logout. To overcome this problem one would need to change the Authentication method for example to form based authentication.

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>webapps</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Similar issue was reported here:

[Logout in JSF with Security managed by Glassfish v3.1](http://www.coderanch.com/t/533724/JSF/java/Logout-JSF-Security-managed-Glassfish)

How to configure Form Based Authentication:

[Using Form-Based Login in JavaServer Faces Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html)

Now that the FORM based authentication is used, it is important to know that the authentication is automatically managed by the container or server for **protected resources**. For example in your case you have provided:

```
   <security-constraint>
        <display-name>admin</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/faces/users/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/groups/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

This means for any /faces/users/* or /faces/groups/* call, the server will check if the user is authenticated and has role of admin. If user is not logged in, server will redirect to **login.xhtml** page. After successful login and authentication the protected page will be shown. If user is logged in but does not have the role then **error.xhtml** will be shown.

You do not need a separate Servlet to make the user login, because server will do that for you. You can simply direct the user to **template.xhtml** page and the container will do the rest. Make sure your template.xhtml is a protected resource fitting in one of the URL patterns as mentioned under security-constraint tag.

Comment: as I said in the comments no Exception for the sign out 

And ur code is giving the same exception

Comment: Tx for the help @ZakiMak , after I've read the solution in the first link , I've created a servlet and I've removed my managed bean "Session.java" ... Now I'm getting : "Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception"       when the login is incorrect ,which is something normal , And I'm getting nothing when it is correct ... Plz help .. I'll update my answer with the servlet and the web.xml

Comment: When the login is not correct the page error.xhtml is redirected and a warning in the Glassfish log appear :
Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
Which is normal 

But when a login is correct the page index.xhtml(login page) is redirected again ... It seems that there's sthg in the web.xml 

And as I understood from ur comment : the servlet is not obligatory ? And if that, how can I redirect the user to a specific page  ? 
NB: in the link that you gave me , They created a servlet

Comment: Did you try by removing the servlet mapping? Also which version of Glassfish is this? Can u test with another server to confirm the problem?